# SQL Query SELECT from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT posts.id AS post_id, categories.id AS category_id, title, contents, posts.date_posted, categories.name, comments.id AS comment_id
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN (categories, comments) ON categories.id = posts.cat_id AND posts.id = comments.post_id
WHERE posts.id = 28
```

I want this SQL Query to select all posts, not just the ones which DO have a comment, but at the moment this query returns those rows wich DO have comments also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
SELECT 
    posts.id AS post_id,
    categories.id AS category_id, 
    title, contents, 
    posts.date_posted, 
    categories.name, 
    comments.id AS comment_id
FROM posts p, categories c, comments co
LEFT JOIN (categories, comments) ON categories.id = posts.cat_id AND posts.id = comments.post_id
WHERE p.cat_id = c.id 
and (co.post_id is null or co.post_id = p.id)
and posts.id = 28
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From Posts P
Left Join Comments C on P.post_id = C.post_id
Join Categories CG CG.id = P.cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think this means?

```
LEFT JOIN (categories, comments) 
ON     categories.id = posts.cat_id 
       AND posts.id = comments.post_id
```

[The documentation suggests](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) the comma separated table list is equivalent to a cross join:

```
LEFT JOIN 
        (
        categories
        cross join
        comments
        )
ON      categories.id = posts.cat_id 
        and comments.post_id = posts.id;
```

Note that this returns all posts, both ones without category, without comments, or without both.  But if no comment is present, this will suppress the category, and vice versa. [See example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bc86/18/1)

A better way to write this would look for categories and comments in their own joins:

```
LEFT JOIN 
        categories
ON      categories.id = posts.cat_id 
LEFT JOIN
        comments
ON      comments.post_id = posts.id
```

If you want only posts without comments, use an exclusive `left join`:

```
LEFT JOIN
        comments
ON      comments.post_id = posts.id
...
WHERE   comments.id is null
```